# Parametrize window by values in row in Pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I would like to add a new column to my Pyspark dataframe using a Window function, where the `rowsBetween` are parametrized by values from columns from the dataframe.

I tried `date_window.rowsBetween(-(F.lit(2) + offset), -offset)`, but Spark tells me `ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.` which I did not expect in this case.

Is there any way to parametrize `rowsBetween` using values from specific columns?

Comment: Can you give some sample input, so we can replicate the error?

Comment: you cant put a col in rowsBetween or rangeBetween clauses. there might be a way a workaround if you could post your complete requirement