# Pyspark - passing a column into a window

Tags: python, pyspark

I have the function below, where F.col("days") is an Integer column

```
def return_window(d):
    days = lambda i: i * 86400  # converts to seconds
    w = Window.partitionBy(
        "a"
    ).orderBy(
        F.col("date").cast("timestamp").cast("long")
    ).rangeBetween(1, days(d))
    return w

df = df.withColumn(
    "total_qty",
    F.sum("qty").over(return_window(F.col("days")))
)
```

I'm getting the error in `return_window`:

```
    ).rangeBetween(1, days(d))
  in rangeBetween
    if end >= Window._FOLLOWING_THRESHOLD:
  File "/scratch/asset-install/6add7b36ad350d9f0c07885622f2e3ae/miniconda36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/column.py", line 907, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError("Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', "
ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.
```

How can I pass a column as an integer to use here? It works when I pass in a real int like `F.sum("qty").over(return_window(5))`

---

The df before doing the window function looks like (if today's 5/20)

```
a      | date | qty       | days
---------------------------------
'alpha'| 5/20 | 2         | 2
'alpha'| 5/21 | 5         | 1
'alpha'| 5/22 | 1         | 4
'alpha'| 5/23 | 4         | 7
'alpha'| 5/24 | 7         | 0
'alpha'| 5/25 | 8         | 0

'beta' | 5/20 | 2         | 2
'beta' | 5/23 | 9         | 5
'beta' | 5/24 | 2         | 1
'beta' | 5/25 | 3         | 6
'beta' | 5/27 | 7         | 3
```

This is what I'd like to add (total_qty is the sum(qty) over the next 1 - "days" days)

```
a      | date | qty       | days | total_qty
--------------------------------------------
'alpha'| 5/20 | 2         | 2    | 6
'alpha'| 5/21 | 5         | 1    | 1
'alpha'| 5/22 | 1         | 4    | 19
'alpha'| 5/23 | 4         | 7    | 15
'alpha'| 5/24 | 7         | 0    | 0
'alpha'| 5/25 | 8         | 0    | 0

'beta' | 5/20 | 2         | 2    | 0
'beta' | 5/23 | 9         | 5    | 12
'beta' | 5/24 | 2         | 1    | 3
'beta' | 5/25 | 3         | 6    | 7
'beta' | 5/27 | 7         | 3    | 0
```

Comment: `rangeBetween` only accept int value not `col`.  could you share sample input and expected output?  There might be a work around.

Comment: @Emma ah that's what i was afraid of :( Added input and output examples!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65323970/2956135